# How much amount of arbitrary data can be included in Beacon PDU?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, gatt, beacon

We're trying to emulate a beacon on a Android device and would like to include some 50 bytes of application data in payload? We found that with AltBeacon format this is not possible? How can it be done with help of AltBeacon lib for Android?
Moreover, what are primary and secondary beacon advertisements?
What is role of GattBeacon in this context and when and how should it be used?

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic types of BLE beacon advertisements:

1. Manufacturer advertisements (iBeacon, AltBeacon, Gimbal)
2. GATT Service Advertisements (Eddystone, UriBeacon, GattBeacon)

They differ mainly by the bluetoorh PDU type, but in both cases the number of bytes that can be transmitted are similarly limited.  It is 23 bytes for manufacturer advertisements (not counting the two byte manufacturer code).

With Bluetooth 4.x, you just won't get close to 50 bytes in a single packet.  Bluetooth 5.0 is expected to increase this at some point in the future.

None of the beacon layouts let you go beyond this limit.  GattBeacon is merely a generic example layout of a beacon based on GATT Service advertisements, and is not meant for practical use.

Comment: What are primary and secondary beacon advertisement? When and how they should be used?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by primary and secondary in this context.  Can you point me to where you are seeing those terms used?